# Convert pandas data frame to categorical for keras

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to preprocess data in python for use in deep learning keras functions.

I use `categorical crossentropy` as loss function in model fit. It requires categorical variable as target.

My target data sample:

```py
    y_train = y_train.astype('category')
    y_train.head()
```

```
            truth
        0   0
        1   0
        2   1
        3   0
        4   0
```

When I tried to convert data frame column to categorical:

```
    num_classes=2
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
```

It produced an error: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`.

How do I convert the data properly?

By the way, which keras models are better for binary classification (yes, no) if I have sample of 3800 observations with 2300 numeric (float32) features each? The features describe mostly graphical objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately i didn't manage to reproduce your error.
Running:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([np.zeros(3),np.ones(3)]) ).astype('int').astype('category')
from keras.utils import to_categorical
to_categorical(a, 2)
```

I get an output:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Maybe it's a versioning issue!

The good news are that you don' t have to use `categorical_crossentropy` for a binary classification problem. You can can use `binary_crossentropy` loss and feed you model with your y_train as a target as it is.

Regarding you last request about which keras model is better for binary classification, Keras pre-trained models are referring to images. You seem to have tabular data, though you wan't be able to use a pre-trained model but you will have to run a custom model on your own.

Comment: My mistake was that there were 3 category in data not two. I converted this column appropriately.